# How to detect a collision between any two points in two vectors of points (C++)?

Tags: vector, collision-detection, point

I have a class like this:

```
class Point
{
public:
   int x;
   int y;

   bool operator==( Point& other )
   {
       return (x == other.x) && (y = other.y);
   }
};
```

Then I have a rudimentary Sprite class which has a vector of points, and many other members/methods which I'm not showing below:

```
class Sprite
{
   std::vector<Point> points;
};
```

Now how do you find any Point in the vector of a Sprite object that collides with any other point in the vector of another Sprite object, using the operator== in the Point class? I've tried something like the following but it doesn't work quite right. **Size()** returns the total number of points in the vector of points and **Points()** returns the vector of points:

```
bool Sprite::CollidesWith( Sprite* other )
{
  for ( int ixThis = 0; ixThis < Size(); ixThis++ ) {
    for ( int ixOther = 0; ixOther < other->Size(); ixOther++ ) {
      if ( points->at(ixThis) == other->Points()->at(ixOther) )
        return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `operator==` is incorrect.

```
   bool operator==( Point& other )
   {
       return (x == other.x) && (y == other.y);
   }
```

Comment: You're right, in my code there is y=other.y instead of y==other.y (I'm sleepy and typing too fast). I've corrected it, and now it seems to be working...

Comment: Cool - glad to have helped!